# Encode string to match encoded form field name in PHP POST array

Tags: php, post, encoding

The name of my HTML checkbox form field is something like this:

```
name = "Some File name.pdf"
```

The PHP POST array looks something like this (some characters replaced by underscore):

```
array(
 "Some_File_name_pdf" => "on"
)
```

Is there a PHP function I can use to convert a filename string exactly as it appears in the POST array? I am not interested in str_replace.
I want to be able to do this:

```
$myfilename = $obj->getFileName(); // returns "Some File name.pdf"
$result = isset($_POST[some_encoding_function($myfilename)]);
```

The some_encoding_function should take a string like "Some File name.pdf" and return something like "Some_File_name_pdf";

Comment: Since both spaces and dots seem to be converted to underscores, there can't be a function that reliably converts them back. But then again, using non-URL-compatible characters in `name` attributes is probably a bad idea anyway.

Comment: I don't mean to convert back. But I mean convert again a filename into same format i.e. replace dots, spaces (and I don't know what else) to underscores.

Comment: The more practical solutions to this problem might be to a) not use arbitrary user supplied values as keys and/or b) encode such keys in a way that does not break after processing (i.e. encode it to something like `Some_File_name_pdf` yourself using your own method).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the PHP documentation](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores.

This would require only a trivial string substitution.
However, according to [a comment on that page](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#81080):

> The full list of field-name characters that PHP converts to _ (underscore) is the following (not just dot):
>   chr(32) ( ) (space)
>   chr(46) (.) (dot)
>   chr(91) ([) (open square bracket)
>   chr(128) - chr(159) (various)

If that comment is correct, then you should be good to go with a function like

```
function underscorify($s)
{
    return preg_replace('/[ \.\[\x80-\x9F]/', '_', $s);
}
```

Note however, that `chr(128) - chr(159)` is ambiguous, as it is not mentioned whether this is character-encoding-dependent or not.
It may refer to all ASCII characters from `€` to `Ÿ`, it may refer to all UTF-8 control characters from `\u0080`-`\u009F`, or it may simply be hardcoded to check the byte value for `b >= 128 && b <= 159`.

Comment: I'd put my money on it meaning any *byte* between 128-159. PHP is not encoding aware in its string handling and couldn't be for arbitrary requests, and the code `chr(128)` literally produces the byte `x80`.